# Coordinating jQuery functions that trigger a page marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**On the site I'm working on, there's a bar that appears:**

**1. When the user hovers over a link**

```
$("#navbar-nav-list-element-left").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-left').toggleClass('bar-active');
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-middle").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-middle').toggleClass('bar-active');
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-right").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-right').toggleClass('bar-active');
});
```

**2. When the user is visiting that link's particular content**

```
$(function(){
 if (/(about.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-middle').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
 } else {
  $('.bar-middle').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
 }
});

$(function(){
 if (/(work.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-left').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
 } else {
  $('.bar-left').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
 }
});

$(function(){
 if (/(contact.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-right').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
 } else {
  $('.bar-right').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
 }
});
```

**3. When the user scrolls down to a specific point on the homepage**

```
$(function(){
  var stickyTop = $('#section2').offset().top;
  $(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
            $('.bar-left').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
        } else {
            $('.bar-left').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
        }
    });
});
```

**My site is a single page application & I'm using [barba.js](http://barbajs.org/) to handle AJAX. Taking that into consideration:**

**These functions run every time the DOM is loaded/refreshed (via .js file included in 'scripts' at bottom of the index page (and only there, since other 'pages' are added via AJAX))**

```
$(function(){
var stickyTop = $('#section2').offset().top;
 $(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
        $('.bar-left').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
    } else {
        $('.bar-left').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
    }
 });
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-left").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-left').toggleClass('bar-active');
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-middle").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-middle').toggleClass('bar-active');
});

$("#navbar-nav-list-element-right").hover(function() {
 $('.bar-right').toggleClass('bar-active');
});
```

**...and these functions run every time barba.js updates content**

```
$(function(){
 if (/(about.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-middle').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
 } else {
  $('.bar-middle').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
 }
});

$(function(){
 if (/(work.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-left').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
 } else {
  $('.bar-left').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
 }
});

$(function(){
 if (/(contact.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-right').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
 } else {
  $('.bar-right').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
 }
});

$(function(){
  var stickyTop = $('#section2').offset().top;
  $(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
            $('.bar-left').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
        } else {
            $('.bar-left').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
        }
    });
});
```

**My Problem:** If I navigate to another page (triggering barba.js) and return to my homepage, *then* scroll until I trigger the bar, the bar remains active after I scroll back to the top.

I'm pretty sure I need to use '.off' on .bar-left, .bar-middle & .bar-right when pages refresh, but I'm unsure how to implement this correctly.

Any advice/constructive criticism/suggestions are much appreciated!

**Here's the full block of code that runs when barba.js is triggered**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
if (!('webkitClipPath' in document.body.style)) {
alert('Sorry, this demo is available just with webkitClipPath. Try with 
Chrome/Safari.');
}

Barba.Pjax.init();
Barba.Prefetch.init();


var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
start: function() {
/**
 * This function is automatically called as soon the Transition starts
 * this.newContainerLoading is a Promise for the loading of the new 
container
 * (Barba.js also comes with an handy Promise polyfill!)
 */

// As soon the loading is finished and the old page is faded out, let's 
fade the new page
Promise
  .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
  .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
},

fadeOut: function() {
/**
 * this.oldContainer is the HTMLElement of the old Container
 */

return $(this.oldContainer).animate({ opacity: 0 }).promise();
},

fadeIn: function() {
/**
 * this.newContainer is the HTMLElement of the new Container
 * At this stage newContainer is on the DOM (inside our #barba-
container and with visibility: hidden)
 * Please note, newContainer is available just after 
newContainerLoading is resolved!
 */
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
var _this = this;
var $el = $(this.newContainer);

$(this.oldContainer).hide();

$el.css({
  visibility : 'visible',
  opacity : 0
});

initFullpagePlugin($el);

$(function(){
if (/(about.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-middle').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
} else {
  $('.bar-middle').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
}
});

$(function(){
if (/(work.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-left').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
} else {
  $('.bar-left').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
}
});

$(function(){
if (/(contact.html)/.test(window.location.href)) {
  $('.bar-right').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
} else {
  $('.bar-right').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
}
});

$(function(){
  var stickyTop = $('#section2').offset().top;
  $(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
            $('.bar-left').addClass('bar-active-scroll');
        } else {
            $('.bar-left').removeClass('bar-active-scroll');
        }
    });
});


$el.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400, function() {
  /**
   * Do not forget to call .done() as soon your transition is finished!
   * .done() will automatically remove from the DOM the old Container
   */
  _this.done();
});
}
});
```

Comment: I have a better idea: How about creating one event handler for any menu item and then using that to call the page name of the menu and returning it via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll admit, as of now my jQuery knowledge is limited (more or less) to what I've demonstrated, and I specifically used Barba.js to avoid *dealing* with AJAX, until I can dig in & familiarize myself properly.

Comment: It will be worth the time to learn.